# how to override clear function in java

Tags: java

this is the basic clear function

```
public void clear()
   // Makes this StringLog empty.
  { 
    log = null;

  }
```

I wand to override it in child class and do

> It is important that the size field be kept up to date as the number
>   of strings in the log change. For example, if the clear method is called,
>   the size should be reset to zero. To ensure this, we need to override the
>   clear method. So, write a new clear method in your MyStringLog class
>   that not only clears all the content from the object, but also resets the
>   size variable to zero.

thank you

Comment: So, what's your question then?

Comment: Okay, so yes, you need to override the `clear` method... what have you tried and what goes wrong?

Comment: How is it possible to do this without knowing what's in the `MyStringLog` class?  I think you'll need to show more of your homework if you want others to do it for you.

Comment: I just do not know how to do that

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to override a method is to write a method in your subclass with the same signature:

```
@Override
public void clear() { ... }
```

The `@Override` annotation isn't required (unless you have non-default compiler settings) but is highly recommended to help catch programming errors. For instance, if the method is declared wrong (and therefore is not overriding an inherited method), the compiler will flag that as an error.

At some point in the method, you probably should call up to the parent class version of the method so it can do its own work. That's done by the statement

```
super.clear();
```